# How I can call the windows Date and Time Process

Tags: c#, .net

I want to allow user to set systems date and time, So when user click on button it will call Date and Time settings. The process name is `rundl32.exe` but I have no idea how to call it for Date time Settings as I can see there are multiple processes with same process name. I am working Windows Application.

Comment: My application is saving datetime of last application run when user run application again I check if current time is greater than previous one, If not it means user changed datetime which is not allowed, and I will force him to set date time.

Comment: This is a very very small concern, but what happens if a user closes your program before daylight savings kicks in, and opens it 30 minutes later? They will be forced to change their time?

Comment: I just want to insure the system Datetime must not be less than previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class

```
Process.Start("control","timedate.cpl");
```